# How to plot Arrow by Arrow in MatheMatica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, contour

I have been studying Optimization recently. I am interested in illustrating how the points move from start to the optimum. 
In the **ContourPlot** tutorial,there is an example using **Epilog**:

```
{min, {steps}} = 
Reap[NMinimize[{(x - 1)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2, 
 x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {{x, -1, -1/2}, {y, -1, -1/2}}, 
StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]];

ContourPlot[(x - 1)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
Contours -> 
Function[{lo, hi}, Exp[Range[0.01, Log[hi], (Log[hi] - 0.01)/10]]], 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], 
Epilog -> {Green, Line[steps], Red, Point[steps]}]
```

But what I want is to Plot like this:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Gradient_descent.png

**An arrow by an arrow**

Thanks very much.

Comment: You have the Arrow[] function http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrow.html but you have to split the line in several Arrow[] calls if you want to show the arrow head in every segment.

Answer (score 0):

replace `Line[steps]` with

```
 Arrow[#]&/@Partition[steps,2,1]
```

untested bu that should get you close.